# Yesod Network.Socket.bind permission denied (permission denied)

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

When trying to execute my project from stack I get this error

```
% stack exec horizon
horizon: Network.Socket.bind: permission denied (Permission denied)
```

Also i get that:

```
% sudo stack --allow-different-user exec horizon
07/May/2018:14:16:10 +0200 [Error#yesod-core] Error handler errored out: 
InternalError "Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 23>: does not exist
(Connection refused)" @(yesod-
core-1.4.37.3-9gXfYzTigbs72LNNfHDGk9:Yesod.Core.Internal.Run ./Yesod
/Core/Internal/Run.hs:233:21)
```

when i try to execute in sudo mode (or with root).

I've already tried to remove ./.stack-works and ~/.stack folders and still don't work

#### Update

The first error was caused using low port (80). In port 3000, either with `stack exec horizon` and `stack exec yesod devel` don't work. I have also reinstalled network and added on extra-deps.

Comment: What are the settings, did you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: I export `127.0.0.1`, but also with localhost is the same, the settings.yml is the standard